# PHP: Is there a way to change request address?

Tags: php, proxy, connection

For some reason, if I request a file using a url such as this:

> http://localhost/proxy.php?url=http://anintranetsite/file.jpg

It works! I can get the file. But if I use,

> http://127.0.0.1/proxy.php?url=http://anintranetsite/file.jpg

I cannot get it to work. I am not unnderstanding what is going on... Any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is there an error? Is localhost in your hosts file? Do you have a virtualhost setup for either localhost or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Hmm... just that the intranet firewall complains that it does not allow access to certain addresses in which it gives me some prefixes like 10.*.*.* and 127.*.*.*. Other than that yes, the localhost is in the hosts file but I do not have any virtualhost setup afaik...

Comment: Good to know, what about any errors? It may sound trivial but exactly how to you know it's not working?

Comment: Oh.. So the way I know it is, when I use this url in the browser to point to an intranet site that gives me an image, with localhost, it works, i.e. it gives me the image (though in a binary format because I'm just echoing the result). But when I replace localhost with the IP address, it points me to a "Restricted" page like one of those 404 pages that says I do not have  permissions to access this page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your browser has the proxy configured wrong.

Aka "No proxy for" should contain localhost AND 127.0.0.1

Comment: Wow! Thanks... That works for the browser... Now is there a global way of setting it so that I can do that even using Java? I mean, I did try the Network Proxy and applying globally in Ubuntu but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: I'm not sure, that would be application specific. However Java has some system variables that would do what you want.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

So for example you'd set http.proxy to your proxy and then add 127.0.0.1 and localhost to nonProxyHosts.

This might work as an environment variable like %HTTP_PROXY% but again that's application specific.

Comment: Actually look at this http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html near the bottom you can specify those variables through command line so you can do it there. Such as java.exe -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="*.mycompany.com|*.mycompany.local|localhost"

Comment: I don't know how I solved it... But its working now... I wrote a small relay proxy and requesting the proxy to talk with the intranet server... Thanks for all the help...

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a router/firewall problem. localhost is probably aliased to your machine name rather than 127.0.0.1

Comment: 127.0.0.1 should always resolve to your local machine - but if you have namebased servers, you might not get the right document root for the 'website' you're trying to access

Comment: Ah... I think I am finally getting somewhere... Do you mind telling me how to modify it so that 127,0.0.1 points to my local machine? Should I be editing the /etc/hosts file or is there any other file? Thanks